# Docker file is not able to be created. Stops in the requirments.txt step

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have these files:

```
version: "3"
services:
  iris-classifier-uplink:
    # if something fails or the server is restarted, the container will restart
    restart: always 
    container_name: text_classification-uplink
    image: text_classification-uplink
    build: 
      # build the iris clasifier image from the Dockerfile in the current directory
      context: .
```

in docker-compose.yml
I also have

```
FROM python:3.8

ADD requirements.txt /

RUN pip install -r  /requirements.txt

ADD text_classification.py /

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

CMD [ "python", "./text_classification.py" ]
```

in Dockerfile.txt
and finally

```
tensorflow-datasets==4.6.0
vega-datasets==0.9.0
scikit-learn==1.0.2
autograd==1.5
numpy==1.21.6
```

in requirements.txt
I also have my python program called "text_classification.py" also in the folder along with the above three files.

When I attempt to make the docker file, I get this output:

```
C:\Vineet\Research>docker build . -f Dockerfile.txt
[+] Building 6.7s (7/8)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.txt                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 36B                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.8                      0.8s
 => CACHED [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.8@sha256:089d758211770a2dd03ecc4  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 7.61kB                                                0.0s
 => [2/4] ADD requirements.txt /                                                   0.0s
 => ERROR [3/4] RUN pip install -r  /requirements.txt                              5.7s
------
 > [3/4] RUN pip install -r  /requirements.txt:
#6 2.749 Collecting en-core-web-sm@ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.4.1/en_core_web_sm-3.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
#6 3.292   Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.4.1/en_core_web_sm-3.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (12.8 MB)
#6 5.139      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 12.8/12.8 MB 7.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#6 5.145 ERROR: jaxlib-0.3.22+cuda11.cudnn805-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
#6 5.584 WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
#6 5.584 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

From what I see, the error is in the requirements.txt file, but I am not sure what is causing the problem.

Comment: Are you sure of the package versions? Seems like your base image is python 3.8 but jaxlib (for spacy) is pulling from python 3.7

Comment: Yes, that helped. Now I am running into a new error :

failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount1231920556/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Comment: Can you please check the name of the dockerfile? It has to be "Dockerfile" without any extensions

Comment: It is Dockerfile.yml, do I have to remove the extension?

Comment: Yes. It has to be 'Dockerfile' only